# User specified css for a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

In general: I have an application with users, very common. I want to allow users to upload css for their user page, and then have that css file load when that page loads in the future.

I'm guessing it could be a simple as adding some controller logic or even in the template (in pseudo)

- if user defined css
  = include_stylesheets @user_stylesheet

or :layout => @user_stylesheet, and have the user defined elements render as a partial

Has anyone done something similar? What I've turned up pertains mostly to theming, but this is allowing the user direct say on the css for a page. It is theming of a sort, but beyond a simple choice I can put in a session.

Comment: Do you have some sort of DB backend?

Comment: Yes, there is a DB backend. Right now, just sqlite for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the file system for this is really the best solution. By just saving a user-provided file (or generating one if the user is filling in CSS in a text box), you don't have to worry about setting Modified headers in order to have the stylesheet cached properly, and since you're just serving static content anyway, you don't have to add any extra load to your Rails app.

If you're on Heroku or anything with a read-only file system, you will probably need to use something like S3 to store the CSS files, but this is relatively simple with gems like Paperclip. I'd also advise saving the potential DB lookup to see whether the user has custom styles on each request. Save the files using a particular naming convention (containing say, the users id) and then just add the link indiscriminately - a 404 error finding the stylesheet isn't really anything to get worried about.

We do something fairly similar, although we just ask users for a few base colors and then have a template SASS / Compass stylesheet we plug the colors into as variables and generate a static CSS file based on those inputs. It works extremely well for us, and has pretty much zero extra computation cost for us.

Comment: Ryan, I want to implement your last suggested solution. Do you have some code or helpful information you can share? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to just upload the entire stylesheet, which would then lay on top of your base styles.  Parse out !Important, first, and reserve that for your own usage.  I've used a similar system in the past.